# debug settings in vc++ 2005

Tags: debugging, visual-c++

While debugging following VC++ simple code,

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) 
{
    // do something
}
```

I want breakpoint should hit the loop when "i = 50". 
Where are the setting for this in vc++ 2005 IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set breakpoint as usual and then use "Condition..." menu item in breakpoint context menu (click with right mouse button on breakpoint circle)